# Trying to add line to ggplot: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to add a line to a ggplot, but I get the error:

`Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (8): x, y, group, colour`

Here's a code that replicates my problem. I first plot two grouped lines, and then want to add another one.

```
a = data.frame(year = c(1:4,1:4), def = c(rep("xx",4),rep("yy",4)), valu = c(3,4,7,8,14,17,11,13))
b = data.frame(year = c(1:4), valu = c(1,9,1,9))
dev.new()
g = ggplot(a, aes(x = year, y = valu, group = def, color = def)) + geom_line()
g = g + geom_line(aes(x = b$year, y = b$valu))
g
```

Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: In the second last line ( `g = g + ... `  ), try `g = g + geom_line(data = b, aes(x = year, y = valu),  inherit.aes=FALSE)`

Comment: Thanks, Sandy, that works!